# How to get specific user project that has membership any project on gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I want to get an user's projects that included as member any project. For example i am included 10 projects in my company but i have no personel project.

https://MyDomain/api/v4/users/USER_ID/projects returns only personel projects.

I need smth like 
https://MyDomainapi/v4/users/USER_ID/MemberedProjects.

Otherwise i have to iterate inside projects members until i got all the membershipped(included) projects for a specific user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [List user projects](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#list-user-projects) which returns only user's personal projects.

You can use [the following to get all projects](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#list-all-projects) where your user is a member of (this include the user's personnal projects):

```
https://<your_domain>/api/v4/projects?membership=true
```